# ruby on rails authentication using devise gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Am using devise gem for authentication

When i run `rake db:migrate`

I got the error mentioned below:

```
rake aborted!
User does not respond to 'devise' method.
```

This usually means you haven't loaded your ORM file or it's being loaded too late.

To fix it, be sure to require 'devise/orm/YOUR_ORM' inside 'config/initializers/devise.rb'

or before your application definition in 'config/application.rb'

If you know answer. Please let me know..

Comment: **To fix it**, be sure to require 'devise/orm/YOUR_ORM' inside 'config/initializers/devise.rb' or before your application definition in 'config/application.rb'

Comment: please look into @Matt post it is perfect...

Answer (score 2):

In the file `config/initializers/devise.rb` look for the line:

```
require 'devise/orm/active_record'
```

Make sure that it isn't commented out, and make sure it matches your orm.

If that file doesn't exist, then you haven't installed devise:

```
rails generate devise:install
```

Have a good read of the [Getting Started](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#getting-started) instructions